# My wordpress.ORG theme breaks comments functionality

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I'm helping to develop a wordpress.ORG website (www.teloscares.org). The site is using a custom theme that I didn't develop (for the record, I know very, very little about php or css) and for some reason the theme is breaking our ability to view or leave comments. IS there any advice on how I can track down what about the themes .php files is breaking it or where I can look it up? Please feel free to point me in the right direction if it's not a quick, easy fix somehow. When I switch to the wordpress "2012" theme it works just fine, which is how I was able to determine that it was our theme. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does the theme even contain the comment-related functions?

Comment: I'm guessing not. I've found everything related to "comments-area" in the 2012 theme and am currently trying to figure out what's what.

Comment: Take a look at single.php in 2012 theme - you'll see where it brings in the commenting template - look in your theme to see if there is anything remotely approaching that in your own theme.

Comment: both single.php pages contain <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?> There are some other things, such as .nav-single + .comments-area, in the 2012 style.css form which are related, but I'm still not sure what I would specifically need.

Comment: I've tried looking around on google with little luck. Is there a good tutorial somewhere online for how I can build a comments box via css?

Comment: It doesn't appear your issue has anything to do with CSS - it's not rendering the HTML for comments/comment reply at all. You very well not have the CSS, but i'd worry about that AFTER you figure out if the comment functions are missing or not.

Comment: Well, when I switch to the 2012 theme comments work just fine, it's only when I switch to the new, custom theme that they don't seem to work. Where would I look into the html?   Edit: Maybe a better question is how do I view/edit the html directly for my wordpress site instead of Wordpress.org's default admin console?

Answer (score 1):

First of all disable all your plugins, see if that fixes the problem? If not then the problem is indeed with your theme. You can track down problems by enabling `WP_DEBUG`, you can do that in the wp-config.php file which you can find in the root of your WordPress installation directory.

*Links from the very mighty codex:*

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug

---

**EDIT**

It appears that the OP's theme didn't have any comment functionality at all, so there wasn't anything wrong it just wasn't there. You can add the comment functionality yourself using `comments_template()`

*More in the mighty codex:*

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did in fact already disable all of my plugins, that's one of the reasons I'm sure it's my custom theme. Additionally, when I switch to the 2012 theme with plugins enabled, comments still work.

Comment: Ok, enable WP_DEBUG in that case! :)

Comment: Thank you very much user2019515. I'm sorry It took me so long to respond, I was sidetracked with a powershell project and had to back burner the webpage. WP_DEBUG isn't reporting anything on the CSS debacle that's breaking comments. Again, when I switch to the 2012 theme they work just fine. It's our custom theme that's breaking them. Can you suggest a good website that may help? Thank you.

Comment: Just had a look at your website, it appears that there's no comments implementation in the single.php of your blogposts. You should add it manually take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) — it's widget is JS-based, has Wordpress integration, supports login with social network accounts and works fine

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It hasn't been tested with our version of wordpress (3.8.1).

Comment: Also, for some reason it's telling me that I didn't install it correctly when I try to verify it on the disqus site. Thank you very much for the recommendation though.

Comment: @JoshAlcorn Please check the permissions for your Wordpress plugin folder.

Comment: OP is asking for advice on how to fix his theme, he's not looking for alternatives.

Comment: Well to be completely honest I'd much rather learn the how/why of doing this myself in case I ever need to again. Using a pre-built solution is fine but it doesn't teach me anything.

Comment: @devlato You have to start somewhere, you can't just start coding full-blown php applications right away.

Comment: @user2019515 wrong, you can just start coding, the good skills and best practices can't be learned without it

Comment: While I thank you both, @devlato I think I am just going to try to figure this out myself. Comments work beautifully with one theme and not at all with another. If I can't figure out how/why and fix it, then I'll feel like I'm doing myself a disservice and kind of a failure as a coder. :) I'd much rather learn something from this then simply ignore the problem and use someone else's software. I appreciate your suggestion tremendously, however.